Adding data-driven command in PyQGIS
I want add to my code line which add option placed label based  to data. I would use string in_mask(0) as string, because i want hide labels under the mask.
layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('layer_name')[0]
settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
format = QgsTextFormat()
settings.setFormat(format)
settings.fieldName = ('label')
settings.isExpression = True
labels = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(settings)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(labels)
layer.triggerRepaint()

I want a command to add the expression or text 'in_mask(0)' in the field indicated in the screenshot.

Could you help me?

cześć :) can you please show the desired output?

@Taras Hi, I have edited my ask with the desired output.
